# Два приложения должны слушать один порт

Tags: c#, .net, сеть, сокет, udp

.Net 4.0, конкретно C#.

По заданию требовалось написать сервер и клиента для udp multicast. Приложухи вроде как работают, но теперь свыше пришло указание сделать так, чтобы на одном компьютере могли работать несколько клиентов (с 1 клиентом и сервером все в норме).

Несколько клиентов биндятся к серверу, но тот, который был подключен вторым, получает оттуда какую-то муть ( похоже, что ничего).

Гугл особо не помог.
НЕ могу поменять протокол, НЕ могу избавиться от многоадресной передачи

Спасибо

Comment: Что именно используется: `UdpClient`? С какими настройками? [JoinMulticastGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ekd1t784(v=vs.110).aspx) смотрели?

Comment: @alexander Без udpclient, просто сокет и joinmultcastgroup